# SQL EXEC(@QUERY) does not have access to global variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

I am writing a query which need to append the database name dynamically.

The query gets values from a table (in another database) , and I would interested to know if there is a better approach/way.

So my query looks like following :

```
DECLARE @TagNames AS VARCHAR(MAX) --Probably this is not a Global variable
DECLARE @QUERY AS VARCHAR(MAX)

        SET @QUERY ='SELECT @TagNames = coalesce( @TagNames + '','','''') +    
                     fldTagName FROM '+ dbo.fnGetZiConfigValue('KEYNAME')+'.dbo.tblTags Where  
                     fldInterpolate = 1 AND fldUnitID = 13'

        EXEC (@QUERY)
```

When I execute this , I get an error,

> Must declare the scalar variable "@TagNames".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is for sure not a global variable. You have to "declare" it inside dynamic SQL and return outside just like you'd do this with stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @TagNames AS VARCHAR(MAX) --Probably this is not a Global variable
DECLARE @QUERY AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @QUERY = N'SELECT @TagNames = coalesce( @TagNames + '','','''') +    
                 fldTagName FROM '+ QUOTENAME(dbo.fnGetZiConfigValue('KEYNAME'))+'.dbo.tblTags Where  
                 fldInterpolate = 1 AND fldUnitID = 13'

exec sp_executesql @QUERY, N'@TagNames VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @TagNames OUTPUT
```

for `sp_executesql` dynamic sql and it's params declaration must be NVarchar.

Comment: on exec sp_executesql , Getting error , Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '@TagNames VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT), @@TagNames OUTPUT, If I close with quotations exec sp_executesql @@QUERY, N'@@TagNames VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT), @@TagNames OUTPUT' the getting an error Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: My bad for @@ (double @) , SO is not letting me with single @

Comment: typo fixed (was `)` instead of `'`).

Comment: Thanks , If you don't mind a followup question , How do I add an extra parameter to the query to substitute hardcoded fldUnitId value. I tried with exec sp_executesql '@QUERY, N'@IPSet VARCHAR(50),@TagNames VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', '@TagNames OUTPUT, but getting this error , The formal parameter "@IPSet" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output.

Comment: Updated this and it's working , exec sp_executesql @QUERY, N'@IPSet VARCHAR(50),@TagNames VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', '@IPSet,@TagNames OUTPUT